# Scraping a table from reddit in R

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I am trying to scrape a table from reddit in R. Here is the link: https://old.reddit.com/r/hiphopheads/comments/9nocy8/twenty_one_pilots_trench_sells_170k_first_week/

I am trying to scrape the main table in the post. Here is my code:

```
library(rvest)
url <- "https://old.reddit.com/r/hiphopheads/comments/9nocy8/twenty_one_pilots_trench_sells_170k_first_week/"
albums <- url %>%
 read_html() %>%
  html_nodes(xpath ='//*[@id="form-t3_9nocy8ire"]/div/div/table') %>%
   html_table()

albums
```

The issue is, this keeps returning me a list of 0. Any help on scraping this properly would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: My guess would be that the table is populated using javascript. If true, you will need to "visit" the page with a phantom browser to execute the code and download the page. At that point, you will be able to scrape the contents. At some point, PhantomJS was such a browser but I don't keep up with the development of webscraping technologies so things might have changed in the mean time.

Comment: https://old.reddit.com/robots.txt explicitly disallows scraping this resource. anyone who provides assistance may be subject to fines or penalties.